# Slight Hissing Sound with Headphones

Tags: sound, lubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

whenever I connect my Headphones to the computer, a slight hissing/white noise can be heard on the background. I believe the cause lays in the Headphones having a mic.

I have searched the internet for solutions, and it seems it has something to do with audio loopback. However, this solutions dont seem to work for me.

E.g.: Many answers consist of disabling loopback in Alsamixer. The problem is, my Alsamixer doesn't show any loopback option.

Thanks in advance,
Schlotty.

Comment: Does this occor with other headphones?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and re-installed paluseaudio and that helped. But try a different headset or earbuds first to see if the hissing is still there, then you know its the headset.